# "Unknown error" and "Failed to create JDBC connection" errors while creating new JDBC in wildfly

Tags: mysql, postgresql, wildfly, wildfly-10

Below "Unknown error" occurs If I try to create a new JDBC (datasource) using wildfly-10.1.0.Final Web Management interface.

```
>  **Unknown error**
> 
> Unexpected HTTP response: 500
> 
> Request {
>     "name" => "PostgresDS",
>     "jta" => true,
>     "enabled" => true,
>     "user-name" => "postgres",
>     "password" => "admin",
>     "jndi-name" => "java:/PostgresDS/School",
>     "use-ccm" => true,
>     "valid-connection-checker-class-name" => "org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLValidConnectionChecker",
>     "pool-name" => "PostgresDS_Pool",
>     "connection-url" => "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/School",
>     "driver-class" => "org.postgresql.Driver",
>     "driver-name" => "postgresql",
>     "background-validation" => true,
>     "exception-sorter-class-name" => "org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLExceptionSorter",
>     "operation" => "add",
>     "address" => [
>         ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
>         ("data-source" => "PostgresDS")
>     ] }
>
```

Then I tried to do it manually by editing standalone.xml file as

```
                 <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/PostgreSQLDS"
 pool-name="PostgreSQLDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                     <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/School</connection-url>
                     <driver>postgresql</driver>
                     <pool>
                         <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                         <initial-pool-size>10</initial-pool-size>
                         <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
                         <prefill>true</prefill>
                     </pool>
                     <security>
                         <user-name>postgres</user-name>
                         <password>admin</password>
                     </security>
                 </datasource>


        <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/mysqlschool" pool-name="MySQL" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
            <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/school</connection-url>
            <driver>mysql</driver>
            <security>
                <user-name>root</user-name>
            </security>
            <statement>
                <prepared-statement-cache-size>100</prepared-statement-cache-size>
                <share-prepared-statements>true</share-prepared-statements>
            </statement>
        </datasource>

...
<drivers>
                    <driver name="postgres" module="org.postgresql">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                        <datasource-class>org.postgresql.Driver</datasource-class>
                    </driver>



...

<driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql.driver">
                <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
            </driver>
...
```

By adding it manually, Now a WildFly Web Management Console shows newly created postgress data source. But by clicking ***Test Connection*** button in WildFLy Web Management Console, it popups below error message:

```
> Failed to create JDBC connection. An internal error occurred. Details
> 
> Unexpected HTTP response: 500
> 
> Request {
>     "address" => [
>         ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
>         ("data-source" => "PostgreSQLDS")
>     ],
>     "operation" => "test-connection-in-pool" }
> 
> Response
> 
> Internal Server Error {
>     "outcome" => "failed",
>     "failure-description" => "WFLYJCA0040: failed to invoke operation: WFLYJCA0042: failed to match pool. Check JndiName:
> java:jboss/datasources/PostgreSQLDS",
>     "rolled-back" => true
```

I had copied postgress jdbc driver ***postgresql-9.4.1210.jre7.jar*** file to:
    C:\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\org\postgresql\main

and module.xml file is also located in the same directory, and is edited as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  

<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="org.postgresql">  
   <resources>  
      <resource-root path="postgresql-9.4.1210.jre7.jar"/>  
   </resources>  
   <dependencies>  
      <module name="javax.api"/>  
      <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>  
   </dependencies>  
</module>
```

my postgrsql database name is **School** and connection limit is set as -1

after being unsuccessful using postgres I also tried mysql but I got exactly same error messages given above while creating mysql datasource from wilefly web interface as well as by manually editing standalone.xml.

mysql driver ***"mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar"*** is located at

> C:\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\com\mysql\driver\main

and at the same location module.xml file is created as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="com.mysql.driver">
 <resources>
  <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar" />
 </resources>
 <dependencies>
  <module name="javax.api"/>
  <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
 </dependencies>
</module>
```

===================================

Wildfly log is as below:

```
2016-09-20 22:37:08,020 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (External Management Request Threads -- 5) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("test-connection-in-pool") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "PostgreSQLDS")
]) - failure description: "WFLYJCA0040: failed to invoke operation: WFLYJCA0042: failed to match pool. Check JndiName: java:jboss/datasources/PostgreSQLDS"
```

and in eclipse console shows:

```
18:24:26,178 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "PostgreSQLDS")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.jdbc-driver.postgresql"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "org.wildfly.data-source.PostgreSQLDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.postgresql]",
        "jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/PostgreSQLDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.postgresql]"
    ]
}
18:24:26,180 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "PostgreSQLDS")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.jdbc-driver.postgresql",
        "jboss.jdbc-driver.postgresql"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "org.wildfly.data-source.PostgreSQLDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.postgresql]",
        "jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/PostgreSQLDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.postgresql]",
        "org.wildfly.data-source.PostgreSQLDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.postgresql]"
    ]
}
18:24:26,197 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "hello1.war" (runtime-name : "hello1.war")
18:24:26,197 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "DemoEAR.ear" (runtime-name : "DemoEAR.ear")
18:24:26,199 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.jdbc-driver.postgresql (missing) dependents: [service org.wildfly.data-source.PostgreSQLDS, service jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/PostgreSQLDS] 

18:24:26,288 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
18:24:26,289 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
18:24:26,289 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) started (with errors) in 5760ms - Started 573 of 844 services (4 services failed or missing dependencies, 433 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
18:25:20,644 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) IJ000604: Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:345)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:352)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:287)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:1320)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:496)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.internalTestConnection(AbstractPool.java:1052)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool.testConnection(OnePool.java:93)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.common.pool.PoolOperations$TestConnectionInPool.invokeCommandOn(PoolOperations.java:234)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.common.pool.PoolOperations$1.execute(PoolOperations.java:90)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:890)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:659)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:370)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1329)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.internalExecute(ModelControllerImpl.java:400)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:222)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DomainApiHandler.handleRequest(DomainApiHandler.java:219)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.encoding.EncodingHandler.handleRequest(EncodingHandler.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.SubjectDoAsHandler$1.run(SubjectDoAsHandler.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.SubjectDoAsHandler$1.run(SubjectDoAsHandler.java:68)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AccessAuditContext.doAs(AccessAuditContext.java:149)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.SubjectDoAsHandler.handleRequest(SubjectDoAsHandler.java:68)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.SubjectDoAsHandler.handleRequest(SubjectDoAsHandler.java:63)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.BlockingHandler.handleRequest(BlockingHandler.java:56)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DomainApiCheckHandler.handleRequest(DomainApiCheckHandler.java:95)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:988)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:341)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2251)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2284)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2083)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:806)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:410)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:328)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:321)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:211)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:300)
    ... 44 more

18:25:20,646 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("test-connection-in-pool") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "MySQL")
]) - failure description: "WFLYJCA0040: failed to invoke operation: WFLYJCA0047: Connection is not valid"
18:26:06,518 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (External Management Request Threads -- 4) IJ000604: Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:345)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:352)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:287)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:1320)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:496)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.internalTestConnection(AbstractPool.java:1052)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool.testConnection(OnePool.java:93)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.common.pool.PoolOperations$TestConnectionInPool.invokeCommandOn(PoolOperations.java:234)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.common.pool.PoolOperations$1.execute(PoolOperations.java:90)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:890)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:659)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:370)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1329)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.internalExecute(ModelControllerImpl.java:400)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:222)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DomainApiHandler.handleRequest(DomainApiHandler.java:219)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.encoding.EncodingHandler.handleRequest(EncodingHandler.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.SubjectDoAsHandler$1.run(SubjectDoAsHandler.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.SubjectDoAsHandler$1.run(SubjectDoAsHandler.java:68)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AccessAuditContext.doAs(AccessAuditContext.java:149)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.SubjectDoAsHandler.handleRequest(SubjectDoAsHandler.java:68)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.SubjectDoAsHandler.handleRequest(SubjectDoAsHandler.java:63)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.BlockingHandler.handleRequest(BlockingHandler.java:56)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DomainApiCheckHandler.handleRequest(DomainApiCheckHandler.java:95)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:988)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:341)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2251)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2284)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2083)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:806)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:410)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:328)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:321)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:211)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:300)
    ... 44 more

18:26:06,521 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (External Management Request Threads -- 4) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("test-connection-in-pool") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "MySQL")
]) - failure description: "WFLYJCA0040: failed to invoke operation: WFLYJCA0047: Connection is not valid"
```

Please if somebody could guideme to fix the problem ... I would be great-full

Comment: For the MySQL connection it looks like the connection was refused. You'd need to ensure the server is running. For the postgresql one when you click the test connection you'll need to look at the logs for further errors.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins where is log located?

Comment: By default on the console or in the `$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/log/server.log` for a standalone server.